# Conditions where magnitudes of dot and cross products of vector pairs are equal?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I want to identify if there are conditions where the magnitudes of the dot product AND cross product of two pairs of vectors are equal. So for vectors AOB and XOY, are there combinations of A,B and X,Y which yield (non-trivial) identical dot and cross product magnitudes? I have checked it out "numerically" by enumerating over (x,0) and (x,y) for a range of x,y and theta between the vectors. I get identity and symmetry-related solutions but do not know if I am missing solutions due to sampling limitations etc. Is there a better (analytical) way to find solutions?

Comment: Are you asking for us to solve $|a\cdot b|=|a\times b|$, or $|a\cdot b|=|x\cdot y|,\,|a\times b|=|x\times y|$?

Comment: the second one of these

Comment: By nontrivial, do you mean we can't set $x=Ra,\,y=Rb$ with $R$ a (possibly improper) rotation matrix?

Comment: The solutions I found were where a and b and x and y were identical or where they were swapped. Any other solutions would be interesting

Comment: @J.G. having understood your comment better, rigid body rotations of a and b would not be interesting. I'm really trying to work out if there are combinations of theta, A and B, and phi, X, Y that yield identical dot & cross product magnitudes if theta != phi